# MUI App bar and blur content below fixed Navbar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

Is there a way to change the background property of my material-ui AppBar component to blur the content blow the fixed navbar?

I've tried the filter: blur(0) and it doesn't work like I want. I have to get this kind of effect on the navbar with React/Styled-components/Material-UI
[image]

I've searched on the internet for many hours...I want, like in the following link for example, get a blur under this appbar : https://codesandbox.io/s/mwbwd?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `sx={{backdropFilter:"blur(20px)"}}` on the Appbar with `color="transparent"` added.

like  `<AppBar color="transparent" sx={{backdropFilter:"blur(20px)"}}>`